# How to check if the system is ready for mounting NTFS by user?

Tags: opensuse, ntfs

There are (too) many posts already on the subject, yet I am stuck.

I found very relevant post here:
[Unable to mount NTFS partition from user account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18191/unable-to-mount-ntfs-partition-from-user-account)

and I also read FAQ here:
http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#useroption

and I still have problem mounting NTFS partition as user. Mounting as root (or mounting with sudo) works. So now I am wondering if my system is ready for mounting with user at all.

My fstab entry options for the volume are:

```
noatime,
noauto,
noexec,
rw,
users,
shortname=lower,
uid=MY_USER,
gid=100,
fmask=111,
dmask=000
```

and when mounting I get error:

> Error opening '/dev/sdc1': Permission denied
>
> Failed to mount
> '/dev/sdc1': Permission denied
>
> Please check '/dev/sdc1' and the ntfs-3g binary permissions, and the mounting user ID.

The requirements are (taken from FAQ):

1. ntfs-3g is compiled with integrated FUSE support
2. the ntfs-3g binary is at least version 1.2506
3. the ntfs-3g binary is set to setuid-root
4. the user has access right to the volume
5. the user has access right to the mount point

5 -- done,

4 - done,

3 -- done,

2 -- ntfs-3g-2010.10.2-2.1.x86_64

1 -- ?

I have no clue how to check if FUSE is compiled within ntfs3g, and how to compare 1.206 version to 2010.10.2 version.

So -- how should I check if it is possible at all to make things work for me? Because maybe my all struggle to mount it from user account are futile, because at my system it is simply not possible.

openSUSE 11.4.

Comment: How do you mount the volume? Using `mount` or `fusermount`? I would guess (no guarantee) that the user must not only be able to use FUSE (i.e. be in the fuse group), but also access the block device?

Comment: I use mount, in all tutorial/guides about using ntfs 3g, I didn't spot any info about using FUSE directly. I have access rights to block device.

Answer (score 2):

`man ntfs-3g` says:

> *If ntfs-3g is set setuid-root* then non-root users will be also able to
>   mount volumes.

`ls -ld $(which ntfs-3g)` says mine lacks setuid. Does your?

Answer (score 0):

add "user" option to your fstab
user - the user option on a line, anybody can **mount** the corresponding system.
users - If any user should be able to **unmount**,  then use users instead of user in the fstab line.

Comment: This is valid for regular mount, but not for NTFS-3G, its FAQ says, that this option is ignored. Just for being sure, I tested it -- no difference.

Comment: are you part of 'disk' group?

Comment: I added myself to this group, logged in again, no change.